# (Beginner / Python) Append or remove entry from list, then print to TextTable

Tags: python-3.x

I just started  learning how to process data in python by converting it from list into table. I wish to know the code to allow user input to append or remove entries into the table. Each entry should comprise of organization name, year of establishment, and current CEO.

Here's my code :

```
# import texttable module
import texttable as tt

# create texttable object
tableObj = tt.Texttable()

# create heading
headings = ["ORGANIZATION", "ESTABLISHED", "CEO"]
tableObj.header(headings)

# create list as row values
organization = ['Google', 'Microsoft', 'Nokia', 'Geeks for Geeks', 'HackerRank']
established = [1998, 1975, 1865, 2008, 2007]
ceo = ["Sundar Pichai","Satya Nadella", "Rajeev Suri", "Sandeep Jain", "Vivek Ravisankar"]

# adding list into row
for row in zip(organization, established, ceo):
tableObj.add_row(row)

# display table
print(tableObj.draw())
```

Thank you everyone! I might post several other questions related to this one in different threads. Have a nice day, and please pardon a newbie :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that this is not a code counseling service. Instead, we focus on [single, specific and objective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your problems are quite broad so you will probably benefit more from a general Pandas tutorial. If you get stuck on a specific issue, please ask a separate question for that.

Comment: Thank you Jan! I will revise my question to be more specific, one at a time, and separate them when necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `append()` method to append an item for example use this code:

```
import texttable as table
def display(i, organization, established, ceo):
    for k in i:
        organization.append(k)
        if k==i[1]:
            established.append(k)
        if k==i[2] :
            ceo.append(k)

    t = table.Texttable()
    headings = ["organization", "established.", "ceo"]
    t.header(headings)
    #t.set_chars(["-"," ","+","~"])
    t.set_deco(table.Texttable.BORDER)
    for row in zip(organization, established, ceo):
        t.add_row(row)
    s = t.draw()
    print(s + "\n")
    return organization, established, ceo
```

this run:

```
`print(display(['Stack',2000,'Salio'],['Google', 'Microsoft', 'Nokia', 'Geeks for Geeks', 'HackerRank'],[1998, 1975, 1865, 2008, 2007],["Sundar Pichai","Satya Nadella", "Rajeev Suri", "Sandeep Jain", "Vivek Ravisankar"])
```

Output add this list `['Stack',2000,'Salio']`

```
   +---------------------------------------------------+
|  organization     established.         ceo        |
| Google            1998           Sundar Pichai    |
| Microsoft         1975           Satya Nadella    |
| Nokia             1865           Rajeev Suri      |
| Geeks for Geeks   2008           Sandeep Jain     |
| HackerRank        2007           Vivek Ravisankar |
| Stack             2000           Salio            |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Similarly, you can remove values by The `remove()` method removes the specified item.